# Why is my Application trying to create a local SQL Server Express database when I add a user to a role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-roles

I am running the code locally, and I have a database setup on a 3-rd party SQL Server and it has 5 tables for UserProfiles/Roles/Membership. I am trying to simply add a user to a role.

Below is my code for that simple exchange:

```
namespace InSight.Controllers
{
public class AdminController : Controller
{
//
// GET: /Admin/
public ActionResult Index()
{
Roles.AddUserToRole("schumacherj","Administrator");
return View();
}

}
}
```

The error that I receive when trying to access the Administrator controller with the offending code:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to >SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name >is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>
> > Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web >request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it >originated in the code.
>
> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance
>   using a database >location within the application's App_Data
>   directory. The provider attempted to >automatically create the
>   application services database because the provider determined >that
>   the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements
>   are necessary >to successfully check for existence of the application
>   services database and automatically >create the application services
>   database:

EDIT:

So.... I asked much too soon.

I followed the advice in this answer:
[Godaddy ASP.NET membership database woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746068/godaddy-asp-net-membership-database-woes)

Then I made a mistake and followed this one's advice:
http://forums.asp.net/t/982572.aspx

I hope this helps someone besides me.

Comment: show the connectionstring

Comment: The connection string wasn't the issue. I had already made successful attempts at a login and stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Express database file auto-creation error in MVC 4 - But i DON'T want to use SQL Server Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889792/sql-server-express-database-file-auto-creation-error-in-mvc-4-but-i-dont-want)